# How to use an outer variable in an anonymous inner class

Tags: java, multithreading

How I can access an outer variable from inside an implicit object created inside a method?

```
public void insertMaterial() {

new Thread(){

  public void run(){
    com.ssn.acx.api.configuration.ParameterSet ps = com.ssn.acx.api.ACXObjectFactory.getConfigurationFactory().getLocalConfiguration().getParameterSet(com.ssn.acx.api.persistence.ACXPersistenceFactory.CFG_DEFAULT);
    com.ssn.acx.api.persistence.ACXPersistenceFactory factory = com.ssn.acx.api.ACXObjectFactory.getPersistenceFactory(ps);
    com.ssn.acx.api.persistence.ACXPersistenceSession session = factory.openSession();
    com.ssn.acx.api.common.transaction.ACXTransaction tx = null;
    WMSMaterial mat = null;

    try {
      tx = session.beginTransaction("InsertMaterial");                    

      mat = new WMSMaterial("101", "Baby Lotion");
      session.getPersistenceSession().insert(mat);          

      mat = new WMSMaterial("102", "Bubble Gum");
      session.getPersistenceSession().insert(mat); 

      mat = new WMSMaterial("103", "Soda");
      session.getPersistenceSession().insert(mat);  

      tx.commit();

    } finally { if (tx != null && !tx.closed()) { tx.rollback(); } session.close(); }//end of try-catch-finally block

  }//end of run method

}.start(); //end of Thread Object creation


}   //end of insertMaterial method
```

For example, I need to have access to `Material` object if it was passed to `insertMaterial()` method args from within the `run()` method which belongs to implicit thread object, instead of creating `Material` object inside the thread object.

Comment: Use `final` or class member.

Comment: Or, in Java 8, ensure that the variable is *effectively final*. That is, even if you don't mark it `final` explicitly, you don't make any changes to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [JLS 8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e9337):

> When an inner class (whose declaration does not occur in a static
>   context) refers to an instance variable that is a member of a
>   lexically enclosing class, the variable of the corresponding lexically
>   enclosing instance is used.
>
> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but
>   not declared in an inner class must be declared final.

It means you can only use an *outside* `final` variable or an enclosing class member in an *anonymous* inner class.

```
/*
 * I suggest this solution, but not this approach, 
 * please be careful with multi-threading programming. :)
 */

// [...]
// private List<WMSMaterial> listMaterials; // or using a class member
// [...]
public void insertMaterial(final List<WMSMaterial> listMaterials) {

new Thread(){

  public void run(){
    com.ssn.acx.api.configuration.ParameterSet ps = com.ssn.acx.api.ACXObjectFactory.getConfigurationFactory().getLocalConfiguration().getParameterSet(com.ssn.acx.api.persistence.ACXPersistenceFactory.CFG_DEFAULT);
    com.ssn.acx.api.persistence.ACXPersistenceFactory factory = com.ssn.acx.api.ACXObjectFactory.getPersistenceFactory(ps);
    com.ssn.acx.api.persistence.ACXPersistenceSession session = factory.openSession();
    com.ssn.acx.api.common.transaction.ACXTransaction tx = null;

    try {
      tx = session.beginTransaction("InsertMaterial");                    

      for (WMSMaterial material : listMaterials) {
          session.getPersistenceSession().insert(material);
      }

      tx.commit();

    } finally { if (tx != null && !tx.closed()) { tx.rollback(); } session.close(); }//end of try-catch-finally block

  }//end of run method

}.start(); //end of Thread Object creation


}   //end of insertMaterial method
```

---

**[Update]**

As @AndyThomas points out in the comment, Java 8 has *effectively final variable* that you do not need to explicitly mark a variable as `final`:

> Certain variables that are not declared final are instead considered *effectively final*:
>
> - It is not declared final.
> - It never occurs as the left hand side in an assignment expression
>     . (Note that the local variable declarator containing the
>     initializer is not an assignment expression.)
> - It never occurs as the operand of a prefix or postfix increment or
>     decrement operator.

[JLS 4.12.4. final Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

Comment: @AndyThomas Thank you, +2 for `effectively final` suggestion. :D I will update the answer.